# Time taken to mount an ext4 fs image

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4

I am trying to understand correlation between time taken to mount an ext4 fs image and size of the image.

Please help me understand how time taken to mount is affected,?

- A large ext4 fs with few small files, lets say 100 MB fs with 10 10 KB files.
- A large ext4 fs with many small files, lets say 100 MB fs with 9,000 10 KB files.
- A large ext4 fs with few big files, e.g., 100 MB fs with 10 10 Mb files

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: Common sense tell me as ext4 is journal FS where should be no significant difference in time. The difference can come from reply the logs

Comment: Do your benchmarks on your hardware. Ext4 is a file system, you cant compare benchmarks for filesystems when working on different hardware/OS